# I try to map the content of an Array i mapped but cant reach it (is not defined no-undef)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, map-function

In my implementation i want to load an array of questions from my JSON database, to play a quiz.
My function loads the questions and maps them. Now after checking if there are still open questions(showscore? in score selection) it should take the questions array and map the answer options. My problem is, that i cant reach the questions('question" is not defined  no-undef) because i am asking for showscore in between. Is there a way to get this to compile?

My code looks like this:(the database are just filler questions for now)

```
import './play_quiz.css';
import React from "react"

class Play_quiz extends React.Component {

    state = {
        currentQuestion: 0,
        showScore: false,
        score: 0,
        questions: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRandomizedQuestions();
        console.log("Current state:")
    }

    getRandomizedQuestions = () => {
        const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/questions'
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    console.log("From database:");
                    console.log(result);

                    let amountOfQuestions = result.length;
                    let randomizedResult = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < amountOfQuestions; i++) {
                       let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length);
                       randomizedResult.push(result[randomIndex]);
                       result.splice(randomIndex, 1);
                    }
                    //const randomizedResult  = result.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
                    this.setState({questions: randomizedResult });
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log('An unexpected error occurred', error);
                }
            );
    };


    handleAnswerOptionClick = (isCorrect) => {
        if (isCorrect) {
            this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 });
        }

        const nextQuestion = this.state.currentQuestion + 1;
        if (nextQuestion < this.state.questions.length) {
            this.setState({
                currentQuestion: nextQuestion
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                showScore: true
            })
        }
    };

    updateCurrentQuestion = () => {
        this.setState({ currentQuestion: this.state.currentQuestion + 1 })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='quiz-window'>
                {this.state.questions.map((question, index) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        {question.title}
                    </div>)
                )
                }
                {this.state.showScore ? (
                    <div className='score-section'>
                        korrekt beantwortet: {this.state.score} von {this.state.questions.length}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                        <div>
                            <div className='question-section'>
                                <div className='question-count'>
                                    <span>Frage {this.updateCurrentQuestion}</span>/{this.state.questions.length}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className='answer-section'>
                                {question.answers.map(answer => (
                                                  <button key={answer.number} onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}>
                                                  {answer.answer}
                                                  </button>
                                    ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Play_quiz;
```

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Pi Dezimal",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": false,
      "question": "Wie lauten die 4 ersten Dezimalstellen von Pi?",
      "answers": "1415",
      "category": null
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Längster Fluss",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": true,
      "question": "Welcher ist der längte Fluss der Welt?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "answer": "Donau",
          "isCorrect": false
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
          "answer": "Nil",
          "isCorrect": true
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
          "answer": "Wolga",
          "isCorrect": false
        },
        {
          "number": 4,
          "answer": "Amazonas",
          "isCorrect": false
        }
      ],
      "category": null
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Energieaufnahme Pflanzen",
      "author": "Timo",
      "isMC": false,
      "question": "Durch welchen Vorgang gewinnen Pflanzen Energie?",
      "answers": "Photosynthese",
      "category": null
    }
  ],


  "quizzes": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "player": "Emil",
      "questions" : [
        {
          "number" : 0,
          "referenceID" : 1,
          "isAnswered" : false,
          "isCorrectlyAnswered" : false
        },
        {
          "number" : 1,
          "referenceID" : 0,
          "isAnswered" : false,
          "isCorrectlyAnswered" : false
        }
      ],
      "grade" : null,
      "editingTime" : null,
      "isFinished" : false
    }
  ],


  "profile": {
    "name": "typicode"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox environment for this? If you can, I would gladly help

Comment: unfortunately i cant provide that.

Comment: ok, i figured out how to do it. Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/c98oe @SinanYaman

Comment: See answer and see if it helps

Comment: You were the one that said you had a new error `TypeError: question.answers.map is not a function`, I was just pointing out your data is inconsistently typed. If you can provide a working, *running* codesandbox (*i.e. fix the undefined `questions` error and mock your fetched data*) then we can start helping you debug it. Please try to reduce it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where do you even try `this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].answers` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you wanted the `question.answers.map` inside `this.state.questions.map` and forgot you close the {} for that, but basically your `question` is not defined without mapping over your `questions` array

Try changing this:

```
{question.answers.map(answer => (
    <button key={answer.number} onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}>
    answer.answer
    </button>
))}
```

to this:

```
              {this.state.questions.map((question) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    {question.answers.map(answer => 
                      <button
                        key={answer.number}
                        onClick={() => this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}>
                        {answer.answer}
                      </button>
                    )}
                  </>
                );
              })}
```

Comment: this doesnt compile unfortunately

Comment: ./src/components/play_quiz.js  
SyntaxError:components\play_quiz.js:   Unexpected token, expected "," (95:17)  
  
  93 |           this.handleAnswerOptionClick(answer.isCorrect)}>  
  94 |         {answer.answer}  
> 95 |         </button>}  
     |                  ^  
  96 |      </>  
  97 |     )   
  98 | }

Comment: there is a new warning now: TypeError: question.answers.map is not a function

Comment: @Erazo Some `answers` are strings, some are arrays. You should account for this, or standardize your data shape.

Comment: i thought data types dont really matter in js?

Comment: @Erazo OFC data types still matter... string objects don't have a `.map` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: ohh didn't see the string ones, yep there is that to solve as well. Check for type before calling .map. Thanks for pointing out @DrewReese

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but that is not even the part where the compiler warning occurs. I still dont understand why it isnt possible to refer to specific answers of the question with 

this.state.questions[this.state.currentQuestion].answers

i mean this.state.currentquestion is a number and should give me the content of that specific place of the array...

Comment: @Erazo replying up in the main comment section to not pollute here.